# getche clears the screen after pressing enter

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

I am experimenting with character input functions in C.Following is the program I am running interchanging getch and getche function calls for experimenting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAX_CHARS   255
int main(){
//getche experiments
    char buffer[MAX_CHARS+1],ch;
    int x = 0;
    while(x<MAX_CHARS&&(ch=getch())!='\r'){//relacing getch here with getche
        buffer[x++]=ch;
        putchar(ch);
    }
    buffer[x]='\0';
    printf("%s",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

- When I run the program with getch(),I get to see the each character
  printed as soon as I enter them through keyboard(thanks to
  putchar),and the whole line once I press enter(thanks to printf
  statement at last).So it is fine.
- When I replaced getch with getche the only difference I expected was
  I would get each of the characters I enter printed twice as soon as I
  enter(since getche echoes the character to stdout) and print the line
  at last after I press enter.But as soon as I press enter whole screen
  is cleared and the line is printed.

Why is the screen getting cleared before printing at last?

Thank you

Comment: Both `getch` and `getche` (and the <conio.h> header itself) are non-standard, so you'll have to specify what compiler and environment you're using - I suspect it's something ancient like Turbo C ?

Comment: @David Scwartz,@Paul R - I am using microsoft visual studio 8 compiler on windows xp 32 bit platform

Comment: OK - I've fixed your tags now to reflect this. You probably want to stick to standard library functions and avoid non-standard legacy APIs such as <conio.h> if you want your code to be portable.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for us to know without knowing what your documentation for `getche` says. There is no such standard function. My guess would be that it writes to a different screen from the one `printf` writes to. The screen is getting cleared because you have switched from one screen ([the raw 'console' screen you echoed to](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Getche)) to another one (the normal terminal your program's standard output is attached to).

What does your platform's documentation for `getche` say?